# Importing module error and relative import error

Tags: python

I went through posts on stackoverflow and I couldn't figure out. Current work around was hard-coding sys.path.append in run.py for the application to run locally.

[![Folder Structure Image][1]][1]

Without path append and I try to run with python3 app/run.py from project folder I receive no module name app error. I have also tried setting python path to project folder from VSCode terminal before running the application as I didn't want to hardcode workaround.

> SET PYTHONPATH="c:\project\directory:$PYTHONPATH"

```
import os, sys
#Project Directory if relative import or no module errors
# sys.path.append(r"C:\\Users\\iswar\\Downloads\\Alembic\\Alembic") 

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
import logging

from app.api import routes as api_routes
```

I'm missing something plain and obvious. I don't have trouble with any other files following the same pattern from dir1.dir2 import moduleName for imports. Please provide suggestions.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYSgH.png

Comment: Is the project run from terminal at `Alembic` directory using something like `python app/run.py`?

Comment: Yes, I use VScode and run from the terminal there from Alembic project folder.

Comment: Under Alembic>app>run.py file is present. Under Alembic>app>api>routes.py file present. @taxevader

Comment: I think this could be an issues with VScode not importing the project directory correctly. Have you tried updating VScode `PYTHONPATH` variable with project absolute directory?

Comment: I did set the pythonpath in the vscode terminal and didn't help. (updated the question)

Comment: Ah, bite me, for windows its $Env:PYTHONPATH = "c:\Users\directory\project\Alembic;$Env:PYTHONPATH" -> it worked.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I meant. I think VSCode should be able to import the project path `c:\Users\directory\project\Alembic` into its `PYTHONPATH` ie `PYTHONPATH="c:\Users\directory\project\Alembic:$PYTHONPATH"`